# best data structure to fit constant deletion in graph

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I'm building a graph in c++ as a vector of integer vectors

```
vector<vector<int> > graph;
```

my problem is:

- the graph is bidirectional, that means

  ```
  if G[u] contains v, G[v] contains u
  ```
- I need to be able to

  ```
  remove any element v from G[u]
  remove u from G[v]
  ```

  in constant time.

And this removal is an operation I'm gonna be repeating a lot, so a single map won't work, cause when I remove an element, the other elements would come one index back.

I'd like to remove an edge (the last index of G[u], for example, so I could use pop_back and get O(1) ), and then remove the corresponding edge in the other vertex' adjacence vector (*and as this is not the main problem of the algorithm I'm writing and it the algorithm must run in linear time, I think there must be a way to make this operations constant*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unordered_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/), the hash-based set, for the internal data structure.

That is, instead of

```
vector<vector<int> > graph;
```

use

```
vector<unordered_set<int>> graph;
```

To find if there is an edge from *u* to *v*:

```
graph[u].find(v) != graph[u].end();
```

If there is such an edge, then to remove it:

```
graph[u].erase(v);
```

All these operations are expected *O(1)*.

Comment: is there a possibility to get some special element in O(1) ? for example, the first element or the last.. cos I need to keep getting some element to travel through the graph